# Arranging Content by current month jquery / php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, date

So I have content like this:

```
<div class="somediv"</div>
<section id="section-one">
<p>some content</p>
</section>
<section id="section-two">
<p>some content</p>
</section>
<section id="section-three">
<p>some content</p>
</section>
</div>
<section id="section-four">
<p>some content</p>
</section>
</div>
```

...and so on up to section-twelve

I'm using the jquery plugin liquid slider
Each section is a new "slide"
I want to show the slides in an order relative to the current month.
I have one section (aka slide) for each month and I want the slider to start on section-seven in July, section-ten in October etc, etc.

How would I go about doing this? I imagine there's a jquery or php solution, I'm open to either one.

Comment: so you want to change the order of the slides or just make the current month be active first?

Comment: Just need the current month to be active first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquid Slider has an option to select the first slide, use the current date to pass the value:

```
$('#slider-id').liquidSlider({
  firstPanelToLoad: new Date().getMonth()+1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
new Date().getMonth()
```

which gives a number between 0 (January) and 11 (December)

Comment: this should be a comment, you're not proving any insight into solving the OP's problem

Comment: @koala_dev Well, I can't do much more if I dont know which jQuery slider is being used.

Comment: it is stated in the question that he's using "liquid slider" but still you're merely referencing a function that is related to the issue but you provide no hint on how he can use it to solve his problem

Comment: @koala_dev Well, finding how to use it should be easy if you read the docs of the official page. I have no idea of that page, so I answered the other part of the question.